# Avoiding Server Failure due to celery worker

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

We are using AWS EC2 instances to run celery on multiple nodes. But sometimes some of the nodes are going down (showing running on AWS but unable to ssh, and also those celery workers do not show up in rabbitmq management tool), Then we have to manually restart those nodes from AWS Console.

Is there any way we can avoid this server failures due to celery ? (these servers only run celery workers)